# CSS conflict with others div

Tags: html, css

I have tried to make a site but when I create a nav its conflict with body. body .main css showing marigin top in nav menu. but I set this for body content

You can check here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpeed/JLjT2/)

**Here is the css code**

```
*{margin: 0;
            padding: 0;}
            nav .navigation {margin: 0;
                 padding: 0;
                 position: fixed;
                 background: #333;
                 z-index: 999;
                 width: 100%}
nav .navigation li{display: inline-block;
                   padding: 5px 10px;}
nav .navigation li a{text-decoration: none;
                     color: #e1e1e1;}
nav .navigation li a:hover{color: #EDEDED}
.main { margin-top: 30px; }
.slide{background-attachment: fixed;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       position: relative;
       padding: 30px;
}
```

Here is the html code

```
 <nav>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li data-slide='1'><a href="#">slide1</a></li>
                <li data-slide='2'><a href="#">slide2</a></li>
                <li data-slide='3'><a href="#">slide3</a></li>
                <li data-slide='4'><a href="#">slide4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="main">
            <div class='slide' id='slide1' data-slide='1' data-stellar-background-ratio='0.5'>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h1>welcome</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i have tried to make nav bar fixed in top.
and body content start from nav menu.
i have use a class .main which for content  but this class when i put margin top my mnav bar also down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the code :

```
nav .navigation {margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;                  
}
```

I have update your js fiddle : `**http://jsfiddle.net/JLjT2/6/.**` Please check

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the 'position: fixed' on the navbar. Change that margin-top: 30px to padding-top: 30px;

Answer (score 1):

Generally when using `position: fixed`, you should specify the position instead of leaving it up to the browser to figure out where to place the element. It's quite unlikely that you'll want the browsers default position when using `position: fixed`, as you're forcing it to come out of the flow anyway.

For example, on your `nav .navigation` selector, add something like `top: 0`.

```
nav .navigation {
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it because u set the position:fix in ( **nav .navigation**)

**delete fix property**, and if you want nev's **position fix**, then add top:0px; in same class

see here

```
nav .navigation
{
                 margin: 0;
                 padding: 0;
                 position: fixed;
                 background: #333;
                 z-index: 999;
                 width: 100%;
                 top:0px;}
```